# Headless raspi not working - android.permission.CONTROL_KEYGUARD

Tags: headless

I have a headless rasp pi running NanoHttpd. It used to work fine a year ago. I've now picked up the project again, updated all the libraries, and I'm getting this error:

```
W/WindowManager: Permission Denial: dismissKeyguard from pid=5283, uid=2000 requires android.permission.CONTROL_KEYGUARD
 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
```

There's no keyboard connected to the pi, and I used to interact with it solely through the server. No buttons anywhere... I don't even open any windows.

I've tried adding

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_KEYGUARD" />
```

but I'm warned that this is only for system apps.

??

Thanks,

John